# Laravel search for relation field value + relation field value equals field value

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I need to perform a query which searches if the value of specific field in a relation + the value of specific field in another relation equals a field value of the main table.

To be more specific, the models are: `JobAd`, `Application`, `Offer`, `ApplicationStatus` and `OfferStatus`. Each `JobAd` has a `workers_needed` field. I want to get all the **job ads** in which their **applications where has status approved** + **offers where has status approved** = **job_ad.workers_needed**.

Each `JobAd` **hasMany** `Application` and `Offer`

Each  `Application` **belongsTo** `ApplicationStatus`

Each `Offer` **belongsTo** `Offerstatus`

Each `ApplicationStatus` and `OfferStatus` have **approved** valued which is **boolean**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that will work (never tried), but you can try to use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) in combination with `havingRaw()`:

```
$data = JobAd::withCount([
        'applications' => function ($query) {$query->where('status', 'approved');},
        'offers'       => function ($query) {$query->where('status', 'approved');},
    ])
    ->havingRaw('applications_count + offers_count = workers_needed')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i think this is right i was mistaken for using sum()

Comment: It almost worked, I only had to do one thing more. I had to add all of the columns of JobAd to a groupBy method at the beginning of the query. Thanks !

Comment: @TheAngelM97 I think it should work (at least for MySQL) without `groupBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

the job_ad.workers_needed. i don't understand but this should give you an idea

```
 $jobs = JobAd::whereHas('applications', function($q){
        $q->where('status', true);
    })->whereHas('offers', function($q){
        $q->where('status', true);
    })->get();
```

Comment: I know about whereHas, but what I need here is more advanced. I need the sum of both the applications and offers which are approved to equal the field workers_needed

Comment: so you want to get all the jobs where sum( count (applications that are approved ) + count(offers that are approved  ) ) = workers_needed  ?

Comment: yes, and I am looking for the most appropriate way to do it. I can easily filter that after I get them all from the database but I don't want to do that everytime because in future I will have to go through 10000 ads to find just one which matches the statement. If I can do this in one query it will be much better

Comment: try change whereHas to withCount and ->havingRaw('SUM(applications_count+offers_count) =  workers_needed')->get(); in the end not sure if this will work